# An error after update the vscode using python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command

Usually I just use `"run python file"` to run the code, and the terminal command is: `python xx.py`.

After I update the vscode, when I press the button, the terminal command changed to: `conda run -xxx`
and this command does't work.

I want to know how to change this feature back.

Comment: Do you have a `.vscode` folder in your current workspace?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's an update of Python Extensin.

> Use conda run for conda environments for running python files and
> installing modules. ([#18479](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18479))

This is the [changelog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.python/changelog)(28 February 2022).

If you want to roll back, you need to install the older version of the Python Extension before 1 month ago.